# Clearing concepts on the exception

Tags: python

Let's say I have a function.

```
def foo(data):
  if data:
     return data[0]
   else:
     raise ValueError('data is empty')


def main_foo(..):
    ele = foo(data)
```

Now, i want to catch that exception as one of my friends commented

```
Please re-raise the errors at main_foo
```

So does that mean I do something like:

```
def main_foo( .. ):
   try:
     ele = foo(data)
    except ValueError:
         logger.log("exception caught")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to log the occurrence of an exception in main_foo, but let some other function actually handle the exception, do this:

```
def main_foo():
    try:
        ele = foo(data)
    except ValueError:
        logger.log("Exception caught")
        raise
```

This will raise the same exception for the caller of main_foo to deal with.